# Match for isInstanceOf

Tags: scala

I have the code in Scala:

```
  def method1(obj: AnyRef) = {
    if (obj == null)  return "null"    

    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Boolean]]) {
      return Arrays.toString(obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Boolean]])
    }
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Char]]) {
     return Arrays.toString(obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Char]])
    }
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Byte]]) {
      return Arrays.toString(obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]])
    }
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[Array[Long]]) {
      return Arrays.toString(obj.asInstanceOf[Array[Long]])
    }
   // and so on....
```

I was thinking about applying `match` here but I couldn't realize how I would do that. Is there any way to make it more efficient in terms of both simplicity and performance?

Comment: If you just need a string representation: `arr.deep.toString` or `arr.mkString("[", ", ", "]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplicity?

```
scala> def f(a: Any) = a match {
     | case _: Array[Int] => "ints"
     | case _: Array[Double] => "dubs"
     | }
f: (a: Any)String

scala> f(Array(1,2,3))
res2: String = ints

scala> f(Array(1.1,2.2,3.3))
res3: String = dubs
```

I guess you meant:

```
def f(a: Any) = a match {
case x: Array[Int] => Arrays.toString(x)
case x: Array[Double] => Arrays.toString(x)
}
```

Comment: that's ok, but how do I make Int, Double (Array[Int], Array[Double]) or something else as a parameter?

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite awake. Do you mean as in the edit? The x has the type you expect.